# How to split string input and convert to integers to calculate output in Python

Tags: python, split

So I'm making a voice assistant in Python and I want it to do math that I input. This code checks if it ends with an integer:

```
    elif text[-1].isdigit() == True:

            basicmath()
```

Then the function basicmath():

```
def basicmath():

    split = text.split(" ")
    in1 = split[0]
    in2 = split[5]
    op = split[3]
    print(op)

    if op == "+":

        m = in1+in2
        worked = "y"
        mathout = str(m)
        print(mathout)

    elif op == "-":

        m = in1-in2
        worked = "y"
        mathout = str(m)
        print(mathout)

    elif op == "*":

        m = in1*in2
        worked = "y"
        mathout = str(m)
        print(mathout)

    elif op == "/":

        m = in1/in2
        worked = "y"
        mathout = str(m)
        print(mathout)
```

My terminal doesn't return any errors, it just doesn't run the lines where you assign the variables in1, in2, and op. I really just need to know how to pull lines from the list made by split(). Please keep in mind that I'm still learning Python. Thank you!

Comment: @rv.kvetch Please provide some helpful suggestions.

Comment: It wasn't a suggestion, it was only a comment. But I guess, I'd also suggest using `str.isdigit` for this?

Comment: @RubiksCubSolver.py Check out [this article](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) for tips on debugging your code. For example, you can add `print()` statements to see the values of variables or what line of code is reached to better understand what is happening.

Comment: @rv.kvetch Then it is unnecessary. The comments section is intended for asking questions or give suggestions to help the OP to improve their question.

Comment: .split is a function that returns an array of strings split by splitter-strings, those splitter-strings are not part of the return array. Therefore if *text = "5 + 4";* and you did *textArr = text.split(" ");* textArr would be equal to {"5", "+", "4"}. only having index 0, 1, and 2

Comment: what is variable text? How do you know python doenst run the lines?

Comment: also, in1+in2 will return a string, since in1 and in2 are strings.  int(in1) + int(in2) will be an integer.

Comment: @Urh I put print() statements every time it executed something new. I removed them in the question for simplicity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off if all of the if cases have the same outcome just simplify your if statement to be

```
if text[-1].isnumeric(): # check last char if numeric
    basicmath()
```

Next lets look at the basicmath() function... In the line `split = text.split(" ")` if `text = "5 + 4"` then `split = {"5", "+", "4"}`, therefore `split[0] = "5"`, `split[1] = "+"`, and `split[2] = "4"` there is no split[5]

try this

```
def basicmath():

split = text.split(" ")
in1 = split[0]
in2 = split[2]
op = split[1]
print(op)

if op == "+":

    m = in1+in2
    worked = "y"
    mathout = str(m)
    print(mathout)

elif op == "-":

    m = in1-in2
    worked = "y"
    mathout = str(m)
    print(mathout)

elif op == "*":

    m = in1*in2
    worked = "y"
    mathout = str(m)
    print(mathout)

elif op == "/":

    m = in1/in2
    worked = "y"
    mathout = str(m)
    print(mathout)
```

Comment: In the first example, you can remove the need for a loop by just checking if `text[-1] in arr`. But note that even this won't work, because arr has integers, but text[-1] is a string. So you might want `int(text[-1])`. Or better yet, just `text[-1].isdigit()`.

Comment: lol yeah let me fix that real quick

Answer (score 0):

Since I cannot comment, I will write an answer.

assuming `text = 'some text 4 x 4'`

```
split = text.split(" ")
```

split is now `['some', 'text', '4', 'x', '4']` Therefore, you must access the right index! The whitespaces have been removed in this case.

```
# split[0] and split[1] are text.
in1 = split[2]
in2 = split[4]
op = split[3]

if op == "x":
    m = in1+in2
    worked = "y"
    mathout = str(m)
    print(mathout)
```

you can also use str methods to find the numeric values.

so instead of hardcoding it in like you are doing, you could do

`list(filter(lambda x: x.isnumeric(),split))` which will return `[4, 4]` for this example and in general would return all elements that are numeric, based on certain logic [which you should read about](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=isnumeric#str.isnumeric).

There is a lot more to say, doing long if elif chains like you are doing is not the right way to go about writing something like this where you expect varied input and is bad coding practice in general. You should look into object oriented programming and possibly see if you can write a class that would parse the text, and functions or a class that will give you certain things one could do with numeric values. As this gets complex, you may want to leverage existing tools. Look into the [Natural Language ToolKit (NLTK)](https://www.nltk.org) for example.